# is there a compiler warning for this?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

Consider the following code snippet:

```
    curve &c = cuts[p.first];
    sort(p.second.begin(),p.second.end(),[&](Point p1, Point p2) {
        return c.ordered(p1,p2);
      });
    if (norm(Point(c.first()) - p.second[0]) > 1)
      cuts.push_back(c.subcurve(c.first(),p.second[0]));
    for (unsigned i = 1 ; i + 2 < p.second.size() ; i += 2)
      cuts.push_back(c.subcurve(p.second[i],p.second[i + 1]));
    if (norm(Point(c.last()) - p.second.back()) > 1)
      c = c.subcurve(p.second.back(),c.last());
```

This is a little piece of OpenCV code, and what matters is that **cuts** is a vector of **curves** and **p.first** is an index into that vector.  In order to make the code more readable, I replaced `cuts[p.first]` with simply `c` because it gets used a lot in the body.

This code is buggy, and it's a bug that I've bumped into more than once.  The problem (you might want to look at the code first and see if you can find it) is that the push of a new element onto `cuts` can invalidate the pointer that is `c`.

Bugs like this should be at least vaguely common (what I'm doing to make the code more readable is reasonable) but are hard to track down, especially if there is randomization or multithreading going on, because the point at which the vector gets reallocated may change from run to run.  But it should be obvious to the compiler, since you're using a pointer into a block of memory that might get reallocated.  And that's my question: is there any way to get a compiler to warn you when you're making this mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a job for code review.  This is way to much work to ask the compiler to figure out.  The code that does the reallocation might not even be in the same translation unit as this code and if it is then there is no way for the compiler to even have a chance.

Comment: I am not compiler expert but I doubt a compiler cannot easilty, if at all, detect bugs like these.

Comment: You might want to try out static analyzers, though I'm not sure if those will help in this case.

Comment: *But it should be obvious to the compiler, since you're using a pointer into a block of memory that might get reallocated.* You are talking dynamic memory here. That's not easy for a compiler to detect.

Comment: I suggest relying on turning up your compiler warnings and using *sanitizers* to help catch these kinds of mistakes.  The burden for program correctness in C++ is upon the programmer.  Alternatively, there are many programming languages that emphasize safety and correctness such that the programmer cannot make these kinds of mistakes (unless the language safety features are explicitly disabled).

Comment: You might still do `auto c = [&](){ return cuts[p.first];};` with `c()` usage, to avoid repetition.

Comment: If it's lots of this, maybe consider using a replacement for std::vector, that never re-allocates? Like, allocate a block of items, but hold a separate index-vector for quick access. Think of a hybrid of std::list and std::vector.

Comment: The above suggestions are moot in the face of *multithreading*.  Your cross-thread accessed and/or mutated vector still needs to have proper **mutex** protection on top of all the other suggestions.

Comment: I don't agree with most of this.  It would be useful for the compiler to have a hack, warning you if the scope of a pointer into a vector includes a push_back onto the vector.  Better, of course, would be for the compiler to keep track of reallocs (which it could certainly do).  I like Jarod42's suggestion, but it won't make the code easier to understand.  :)  For performance reasons, I can't change languages or data structures, or add a run-time sanitizer.  This is very much what compiler warnings *should* do.